# Why is my alphabetical index empty in Libreoffice Writer?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I have a LibreOffice Writer document, about 64,000 words, divided into 8 chapters. I would like to create an alphabetical index.

I select `Insert -> Indexes and Tables... -> Indexes and Tables`. In the dialogue box that comes up, under `Type`, I select `Alphabetical Index`. I change the `Title` to "Index". Everything else I leave default.

What I get is one header that says "Index" and absolutely nothing else.

I have looked through the options and nothing else seems to make any difference. I've looked online, and it seems like the default options should at least produce some kind of output.

Why am I not seeing any index of any kind being built, and how do I change that so that I can make my index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't write that you've **added any index entries**. It's *possible* to create an index even there are no index entries defined, but in this case, the index *stays empty until you define which entries to put into the index*.

The LO documentation is a little bit misleading in that point - there's an own chapter on [**`defining index entries`**](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Defining_Index_or_Table_of_Contents_Entries). The OpenOffice.org Writer documentation [**explains all steps together**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Alphabetic_indexes).

Comment: I actually naively thought that the index did some kind of filtering of the text for key words. Now that I see the instructions for defining index entries, that makes a lot more sense.